# Can't we use passive simple past?

Tags: modal-verbs, passive-voice

Why do we use passive present perfect like in this sentence?

> If the bribe were given, it must *have been given* to officials.

Can't we use passive simple past?

Also, why  can't we use past perfect 'had been given' instead of 'have been given'?

Comment: Why can't we use past perfect 'had been given' instead of 'have been given'?

Answer (score 2):

The verb in your sentence is not the present perfect *have been given*.

The verb in your sentence is *must have been given*. You can call it the modal perfect passive.

Here the modal is *must*; the perfect is indicated by *have*; and the passive is indicated by *been given*.

A modal verb such as *must* (other modals include *will, would, shall,  can, could, may, ought,* and *dare*) is followed by the bare infinitive. It cannot be followed by a verb that is finite.

The *has* in the present perfect passive  *it has been given* is a finite verb,  conjugated for tense (present), person (third), and number (singular).

The *have* in the modal perfect passive *it must have been given* is non-finite, and does not indicate tense, person,   or number.

In standard English, the following forms do not occur:

*must had been (given)
*must has been (given)

The modal perfect *must have* refers to a completed action. Thus a speaker  can use it to express 100% certainty about a past occurrence. The same is true for the modal perfect passive *must have been*.

Thus *it must have been given to officials* expresses the speaker's certainty that *if* a bribe was given, the speaker is 100% certain that the bribe was given to officials.

In short, we use *must  have* (active construction) and *must have been* (passive construction) to talk about our *certainty* concerning a past action or state. Note that this *certainty* of the speaker does not have to actually be what happened.

> It must have rained.

I'm 100% certain in my belief that it rained.

> I thought it must have rained,  but it didn't.

I was 100% certain that it rained, but in fact it didn't actually rain.

For more information on modals and how other modals express different amounts of certainty or possibility, see the [Modal Tutorial](http://www.englishpage.com/modals/modalintro.html) at English Page dot com.

Comment: So for active I can say that "she didn't give me the address she must have given me" and for passive "she didn't give me the address it must have been given to me by her".

Comment: I am reluctant to call it modal **perfect** passive as the perfect aspect doesn't go well with an adverb or adverbial phrases such as yesterday as in "it has rained yesterday" which is ungrammatical. But "It must have rained yesterday" is grammatical. It means "must have + past participle" construction indicates the past tense of the modal verb, not the **perfect** aspect of it. A modal verb can't be followed by finite forms as you mentioned, that's why the past form of the modal verb should be made with "modal + have + past participle". Do you have any reference or link to support your point?

Comment: I also don't agree with "The has in the present perfect passive it has been given is a finite verb". I would not call it a finite verb.

Comment: Then if we say "it must be done soon" then **be** is not finite form? also if this is not like perfect passive then why we add **been** like we add in present perfect passive construction i.e "must have been given(by someone)

Comment: @Rocky The *be* in *must be done* is not a finite verb, it is the bare infinitive. Infinitives are by definition, non-finite!  This includes the to-infinitive and the bare infinitive.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very important rule that you have to follow in English. A "bare infinitive" or "base form of verb" should follow all the modal verbs such as "must". That's why "had" can't follow "must" as it is the past form of to "have".

Now, I am not sure what you mean by "passive simple past", but if you mean "must had been given" by it, it is plainly wrong. It should be "must have been given".

"Must have been given" is not in the present perfect tense. It is in the past tense and it is used when we are very sure about what happened in the past.

You can visit the [link](http://www.myenglishteacher.eu/question/modal-verb-have-past-participle/) to learn more about how it works.

Comment: What happen when we are not sure about event should we use "would have been given" ?

Comment: @Rocky Try to look up "could have + past participle" and "might have + past participle".